# in Python 2.7, why do I have to enclose an `int` in brackets when I want to call a method on it?

Tags: python

in Python 2.7, why do I have to enclose an `int` in brackets when I want to call a method on it?

```
>>> 5.bit_length()
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> (5).bit_length()
3
```

Comment: A space between the value and the dot would do just as well to satisfy the parser: `5 .bit_length()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's a parser idiosyncrasy.

When Python sees the `.`, it starts looking for decimals. Your decimal is a `b`, so that fails.

If you do `(5).bit_length()`, then Python will *first* parse what's between the `()`, and *then* look for the `bit_length` method.

---

If you try:

```
5..zzz
```

You'll get the `AttributeError` you expect. This won't work for integers though: `5.` is a float.

Answer (score 4):

Because `5.something` would be parsed as a floating point number.